# Mysql update statement executes too slowly

Tags: mysql, sql-update

There are two tables as follows in my problem.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_user_relation` (
  `User_id` INT(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  ,
  `Follow_id` INT(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`,Follow_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_user_info`(
    `User_id` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL  ,
    `User_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
    `User_avatar` varchar(60) NOT NULL ,
    `Msg_count` int(32) unsigned DEFAULT '0' ,
    `Fans_count` int(32) unsigned DEFAULT '0' ,
    `Follow_count` int(32) unsigned DEFAULT '0' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I am trying to do is to update the Fans_count filed of the t_user_info table. My update statement is as follows:

```
 UPDATE t_user_info set t_user_info.Fans_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_user_relation
 WHERE t_user_relation.Follow_id=t_user_info.User_id);
```

But it execute really slow! The table t_user_info consist of 20,445 records and t_user_relation consist of 1,809,915 records.Can anyone help me improve the speed! Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Check the "EXPLAIN" for >>
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_user_relation  WHERE t_user_relation.Follow_id=t_user_info.User_id
  <<

Comment: This particular query -   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_user_relation WHERE t_user_relation.Follow_id=t_user_info.User_id

Try to change it to - 
>>
SELECT COUNT(t_user_relation.Follow_id) FROM t_user_relation INNER JOIN (t_user_info) ON (t_user_relation.Follow_id=t_user_info.User_id)
<<
Check EXPLAIN FOR BOTH THE SELECT Queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

```
UPDATE
  t_user_info inner join
  (SELECT Follow_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
   FROM t_user_relation
   GROUP BY Follow_id) s
  on t_user_info.User_id=s.Follow_id
SET t_user_info.Fans_count=s.cnt
```

I'm using a subquery to calculate the count of rows for every `Follow_id` in table `t_user_relation`:

```
SELECT Follow_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM t_user_relation
GROUP BY Follow_id
```

I am then joining the result of this query with `t_user_info`, and I am updating `Fans_count` where the join succeeds, setting it to the count calculated in the subquery.

A query written like this usually runs faster because the resulting rows from the subquery are calculated only once, before the join, while in your solution your subquery is calculated once for every user row.

Comment: And add an index on `t_user_relation (Follow_id)`

Comment: It finished the update just in one second, what is the magic behind the statement, can you explain it more? Thanks very much!!!

Comment: @Chasefornone you're welcome :) i added a little explanation... let me know if it's okay!

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a large number of records on a DB you want to stay away from the wildcard (`*`) and utilize [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: The wildcard is to be avoided in a select: `SELECT *`. Inside a count `COUNT(*)` is irrelevant.

Comment: I dont think the wild card has anything to do in MySQL. Its the co related subquery to be improved

Comment: @ypercube Just saying, I never said anything about `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @bobthyasian Sorry then, I misunderstood. but the wildcard is only used in a COUNT in the question, so why is this included in your answer?

Comment: @ypercube I wanted to state it; let it bounce around in the back of everyone's mind. It's a good practice. The more it's beaten in the higher chances it sticks.